Is it possible to get shape position during or after animation?
I want to check collisions after or during an animation. Is there any way to do it or what is the easiest way to do it?
I tried collisions checking during animation and it didn't work, so is there any other way of doing this?

I doubt that you can run a Macro while a Powerpoint animation runs.

Sorry, this is not possible. PowerPoint calculates object position from the starting point and does not track position after that.
